# JavaScript: Should object contain method to render itself?

Tags: javascript, html, render

I'm developing an 2D game in JavaScript. The game is rendered to HTML5 Canvas. There are many game object classes, inheriting from each other,...

My question is, should every rendered object have some method called `render`, that gets called by Renderer every frame, or should Renderer contain required methods to draw any game object based on it's properties (points, rotation, color, texture,...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I think for principles of separation of concerns, there should be a separate renderer to the renderee.

I found a series of articles on the IBM Developer Works site (about 9 of them) by David Geary implementing a 2D HTML game called Snail Bait very very useful for game architecture. In his architecture he has a `sprite` and an `artist` to separate the concerns

Link [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/java/libraryview.jsp?search_by=HTML5%20game%20development:) if are interested to have a look

Comment: +1, though I'm sure that each artist has its own sprite, not the frame renderer knowing about all possible sprites.

Answer (score 1):

> Renderer contain required methods to draw any game object based on
>   it's properties (points, rotation, color, texture,...)

You'll find your code much easier to manage if you do it this way.